# create single array of objetcs from multiple arrays of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
[  { name : bob , dinner : pizza },
   { name : john , dinner : sushi },
   { name : larry, dinner : hummus }
]
[  { name : bob1 , dinner : pizza1 },
   { name : john1 , dinner : sushi1 },
   { name : larry1, dinner : hummus1 }
]
```

Now i want to crrate single array where i can store array of objects:

```
[  
       { name : bob , dinner : pizza },
       { name : john , dinner : sushi },
       { name : larry, dinner : hummus },
       { name : bob1 , dinner : pizza1 },
       { name : john1 , dinner : sushi1 },
       { name : larry1, dinner : hummus1 }
    ]
```

I use the approach but that not work

```
const arrayHolder = assetArray.reduce((f, x, i) => {
          f = [...f, ...x];
          return f;
        }, []);
```

any suggestion is really appreciated

Comment: Your input doesn't look so valid, strings need to be enclosed in delimiters. Also, if that's supposed to be one big array with two items which are arrays, you need `[` and `]`s to indicate the big array, and a comma between the array items

Answer (score 0):

Use flat function from array:

```js
const arr = [
      [  { name : 'bob' , dinner : 'pizza' },
       { name : 'john' , dinner : 'sushi' },
       { name : 'larry', dinner : 'hummus' }
      ],
      [  { name : 'bob1' , dinner : 'pizza1' },
        { name : 'john1' , dinner : 'sushi1' },
        { name : 'larry1', dinner : 'hummus1' }
      ]
    ]
    
console.log(arr.flat())
```

Comment: Really appreciate for the suggestion @omri_saadon